# JSON.parse(), reconnecting to nested objects

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having trouble converting JSON to Javascript objects when the JSON data has nested objects.  The top level 'Person' object gets recreated fine, but the 'Residence' object property does not

```
function Person(first, last) {
    this.FirstName = first;
    this.LastName = last;
    this.Residence = {};
}

Person.Revive = function (data) {
    return new Person(data.FirstName, data.LastName);
}

Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "FullName", {
    get: function() { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; }
});

Person.prototype.toJSON = function () {
   this.__class__ = "Person";
    return this;
});

function Residence(lat, long) {
    this.Latitude = lat;
    this.Longitude = long;
}

Residence.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    this.__class__ = "Residence";
    return this;
}

Residence.Revive = function (data) {
    return new Residence(data.Latitude, data.Longitude);
}

Object.defineProperty(Residence.prototype, "Location", {
    get: function () { return this.Latitude + ", " + this.Longitude; }
});

var p = new Person("Foo", "Bar");
p.Residence = new Residence(44, 33);

console.log("Full name = " + p.FullName);
console.log("Location = " + p.Residence.Location);

var serialization = JSON.stringify(p);
console.log(serialization);

var rawObj = JSON.parse(serialization, function (key, value) {
    if (value instanceof Object && value.__class__ == 'Person') {
        return Person.Revive(value);
    }
    if (value instanceof Object && value.__class__ == 'Residence') {
        return Residence.Revive(value);
    }
    return value;
});
console.log("Full name = " + rawObj.FullName);
console.log("Location = " + rawObj.Residence.Location);
```

The JSON.parse function does get a key/value pair for the 'Residence' object, and a new Residence object is created and returned.  However, the resulting 'rawObj.Residence' is just an empty object.  Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

The console output is as follows:

```
Full name = Foo Bar
Location = 44, 33
{"FirstName":"Foo","LastName":"Bar","Age":22,"Residence":{"Latitude":44,"Longitude":33,"__class__":"Residence"},"__class__":"Person"}
Full name = Foo Bar
Location = undefined
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CadGuy/yyq4dqtx/

Comment: Btw, JS name conventions are that properties are lower (camel) cased

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> var p = new Person("Foo", "Bar");
> p.Residence = new Residence(44, 33);
> ```

Well, if you are constructing your `Person` objects like that, you'll have to revive them like this as well:

```
Person.Revive = function (data) {
    var p = new Person(data.FirstName, data.LastName);
    p.Residence = data.Residence;
    return p;
};
```

Of course, it might be a good idea to make the residence an (optional?) parameter to `Person` in the first place.

Comment: Beat me to it. I had just started typing my answer when you posted it

Comment: Making ``Residence`` optional is pretty easy to do. Inside the ``Revive`` function, ``p.Residence = data.Residence || new Residence(0, 0);`` or something like that.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: I meant to make it an optional parameter to the `Person` constructor function, not to make the property optional.

Comment: @Bergi: Good to know.  I changed the Person.Revive method:  `Person.Revive = function (data) {
    var p = new Person(data.FirstName, data.LastName);
    p.Residence = Residence.Revive(data.Residence);
    return p;
}`    This restores p.Residence to a valid object. Does this make sense?